# Use Autofac for non-registered type initialization

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a library that builds instances of types (all public and non-abstract) it discovers dynamically at runtime (using reflection).

To build those instances I want to use Autofac (though I'm willing to use other frameworks) so that the dependencies are automatically incorporated.

The problem is that Autofac is not creating the instance. If I use `scope.Resolve()` it throws an exception saying the type wasn't registered (which it can't be since it is discovered dynamically at runtime). If I try to use `scope.ResolveOptional()` it just returns null.

I've used it with types that have just a default public constructor and types that have dependencies and both fail.

**EDIT:** Added code. The types returned in the `types` array are all public types with a default parameterless constructor.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                   .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                   .Where(p => typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(p) 
                                               && !p.IsAbstract
                                               && p.IsPublic).ToArray();

var instance = (ISomeInterface)_dependencyInjectionScope.Resolve(type);
```

**EDIT 2:** Regarding some comments, yes I know that these types are not registered beforehand but that happens because the container is already fully built by the time this code is called. I'm looking if there is a way around it (after all I'm providing Autofac with a type that is both concrete and constructable)

Comment: How do you create instances of your objects before adding Autofac?

Comment: Right now I just use Activator.CreateInstance and default constructors. But since I want to be able to inject dependencies, that is not a particularly nice mechaniusm

Comment: You need to share some code, otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: @thepirat000 Are you sure? *The problem is that Autofac is not creating the instance. ... throws an exception saying the type wasn't registered* might indicate dynamic runtime resolving without registration. But, just a guess.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you eventually looking for [Registration Sources](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html)?
If so, please see the [`AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html#any-concrete-type-not-already-registered-source):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());
var container = builder.Build();
```

Comment: I knew many others must have had the same problem as me. And so, the simple answer takes it :)

Comment: Can this be added via configuration (app.config) instead of modifying code?

Answer (score -2):

> though I'm willing to use other frameworks

You can use the [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/) container. It allows you to build objects of any class (not interfaces) without explicitly registering the classes with the container. Of course the classes have to be public, non-abstract, have a public constructor, and interface-based dependencies should be registered with the container.

Here is a sample code:

```
public interface IService
{
}

public class Service : IService
{

}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IService m_Service;

    public MyClass(IService service)
    {
        m_Service = service;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(); //We need to register interface-based dependency

        var my_class = container.Resolve<MyClass>(); //We can resolve class-based types without registering them explicitly
    }
}
```

Comment: Why suggesting Unity here? This can be done with Autofac as well: `builder.RegisterType<Service>().As<IService>()` - I still don't get the point of this answer ...

Comment: Does Autofac support resolving MyClass without registering it?

Comment: Without explicitely registering it? Partially, through [Assembly Scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html), but better with [Registration Sources](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html#any-concrete-type-not-already-registered-source).

Comment: It seemed to me that this is what the question is about. They want to be able to construct an object without registering it explicitly because they discover it at runtime. Unity can resolve class-based objects without registering them.

Comment: I am not a fan of Unity. I am not a fan even in DI containers. I encourage people not to use them in the first place. See my article [here](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html). But Unity has a feature that I though Autofac does not have. Which is the ability to resolve class-based objects without registering them. I still cannot see how you can do this in Autofac. Also, note that in the question they stated that they are willing to use another container.

Comment: <strike>Autofac can do this as well ... Please pardon me, but why throw in *Unity* if the question was about a feature of Autofac (which it also provides) ...?</strike> Uuups, sorry ... I've overlooked *though I'm willing to use other frameworks* - Sorry!

Comment: Anyway, you do know that your answer doesn't reflect that feature of Unity as you are still registering the type?

Comment: Don't worry. It was easier for me to answer about Unity since I know it has the required feature and the person who asked is willing to use any framework. Thanks to you, I learned something new Today about Autofac. In my answer I am using the feature since I am not registering the MyClass type. I am only registering the IService type.

Comment: True that - once again, overlooked crucial code parts ... I should get some sleep ...